# Dask compute on dataframe to add column returns AttributeError

Tags: python, json, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a function that adds a column to a DataFrame using a function, for eg

```py
    def myfunc(x):
        resp_data = {'status': '1', 'data': x}
        return json.dumps(resp_data)
```

The original Pandas dataframe `df` is converted into `Dask` DataFrame as follows

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=30)
```

Now I call the function `myfunc` on `ddf` to add new column `data_json` using existing column `att` as follows

```
ddf['data_json'] = ddf.apply(lambda row:myfunc(row['att']), 
                   axis=1, result_type='expand', meta=(None, 'str'))
```

When I call `ddf.compute()` it breaks with this error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I need to save `ddf` to a file after calling `compute()` using

```
ddf.to_csv("myfile.csv",  index=False, single_file=True)
```

How can I handle the error to skip those rows where this is generated and continue to process and save the Dask dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- if your function is simple, then it is not necessary to pass the series as an argument, so something like `ddf.apply(myfunc, axis=1)` should work. If the function takes multiple arguments, then content of the function should specify how to handle multiple columns.
- turns out `json` doesn't like `numpy` dtypes, so before dumping the value needs to be converted using `int`.
- if the dataframe is saved to csv, then there is no neeed to `.compute` it before, as it will involve doing same work twice.
- if `myfunc` does not depend on the neighbouring rows, one could also use `.map_partitions`.

```py
import json

import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(range(5), columns=["x"]), npartitions=2)
ddf["y"] = 2 * ddf["x"]


def myfunc(row):
    """content of the function should specify how to handle different columns"""
    resp_data = {
        "status": "1",
        "y": int(row["y"]),
        "diff_data": int(row["y"] - row["x"]),
    }
    return json.dumps(resp_data)


ddf["data_json"] = ddf.apply(myfunc, axis=1, result_type="expand", meta=(None, "str"))

print(ddf.compute())
#    x  y                                data_json
# 0  0  0  {"status": "1", "y": 0, "diff_data": 0}
# 1  1  2  {"status": "1", "y": 2, "diff_data": 1}
# 2  2  4  {"status": "1", "y": 4, "diff_data": 2}
# 3  3  6  {"status": "1", "y": 6, "diff_data": 3}
# 4  4  8  {"status": "1", "y": 8, "diff_data": 4}

# if the dataframe only needs to be saved, there is no need for separate .compute
# ddf.to_csv("myfile.csv", index=False, single_file=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, `myfunc` is a bit complex and takes multiple columns of `ddf` as input and returns a `GeoDataFrame` `__geo_interface__` as output. In that case would it be better to call `compute()` after `apply` separately on `ddf` or as you have done?

Comment: Kindly check the updated example.